# How can I create a form without using resources (action :new, :create) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my controller

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.new
  end

  def form_create
    @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
    if teacher.save
      redirect_to schools_teacher_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "error"
    end
  end

  private
  def teacher_params
    params.require(:teacher).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

This is my views/schools/teacher.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :teacher do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If you are using Rails 5.1, I would recommend reading this article [Rails 5.1's form_with vs. form_tag vs. form_for](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a)

Comment: you should put this logic into TeachersController and create the actions `new` and `create`. There is no need to go against the convention

Comment: That article is extremely useful thanks

Comment: Go through link for more understanding http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  especially **Non-Resourceful Routes**

Comment: why is everyone showing him how to dismiss the convention instead of teaching how it should be done properly?

Answer (score 1):

You should move this to a `TeachersController` let me show you how:

First you need to create the controller, you can get this done by typing this on the terminal at the project root directory:

`$ rails g controller teachers new`

Then into your route file (`config/routes.rb`):

```
resources :teachers, only: [:new, :create]
```

After that go to the `teachers_controller.rb` file and add the following:

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @teacher = Teacher.new
  end

  def reate
   @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
   if @teacher.save
    redirect_to schools_teacher_path
   else
    redirect_to schools_teacher_path, notice: "error"
  end
end

 private

 def teacher_params
  params.require(:teacher).permit(:name)
 end
end
```

Then you can have the form at `views/teachers/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for :teacher do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %> 
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know how it goes!